# Correcting a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, io, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i=0,n,h,k;
    k = (int)pow(10,5);
    int c[k];
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&h);

    if((n>=1 && n<=(int)pow(10,5)) && (h>=1 && h<=(int)pow(10,8))){ 
      int arr[n];

      do{
          scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
          if(arr[i] > h){
            cout<<"Error !";
            exit(1);
          }
          i++;
      }while(i!=(n-1));

      i=0;

      do{                    /*The fault occurs somewhere here, probably*/
          scanf("%d",&c[i]);
          i++;
      }while(c[i]!=0);

      if(i>(int)pow(10,5)){
          cerr<<"Error !";
          exit(0);
      }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to accept a few numbers from the console on different lines using scanf() (with certain constraints on the upper and lower limits of the numbers) - The problem is that I'm getting a segmentation fault somewhere around where I've put a comment - I can't seem to figure out where the fault occurs - could someone point out the mistake I've made ?

Comment: `k = (int)pow(10,5); int c[k];`  This isn't valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have compile-time expressions to denote the number of entries.

Comment: What would be the correct statement ?

Comment: The "statement" is to use `std::vector<int> c(k);`

Comment: What numbers are you giving it? I see at least three serious bugs, but I don't know the exact cause of your error.

Comment: @Beta Each of the numbers going to the c[] array has the upper-limit 10^8.

Comment: Are we playing 20 Questions? What numbers are you giving it?

Comment: Also, use constants and don't call `pow`.  The `pow` function is going to go through a gauntlet of floating point code to calculate the power.  In addition, there is that ever slight chance that `pow` can yield an inexact answer.

Comment: @Beta  line 1: 7 4 ; line 2 : 3 1 2 1 4 0 1 ; line 3 : 3 2 2 2 2 4 1 3 1 4 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is here

```
do{                  
     scanf("%d",&c[i]);
     i++;
 }while(c[i]!=0);
```

Consider current value of `i` is `0` and you are entering value at `c[0]` after that increamenting value of `i`. Now `i` become `1` and then you are checking `c[1] != 0` this is the problem

use

```
i=-1;

do{     
     i++;             
     scanf("%d",&c[i]);
  }while(c[i]!=0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d",c[i])` should be  `scanf("%d",&c[i])`

Comment: Or simply `std::cin >> c[i];`.

Comment: @tnishada I corrected that - the segmentation fault is corrected it seems - now it does not run the do-while loop where I put the comment - it exits just before that.